# Using Laplace Transform to solve ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I have to solve the following ODE using the table of Laplace transforms

$y''-y'+y= δ(t − 2)  , y(0)=1$ and $y'(0)= 0$

This is my work, yet I am not even close to the answer. If someone could help me understand what I'm doing wrong this would be very helpful!!
[image]

Comment: $s^2-s+1\neq (s-1)^2$. So the simplifications you pursue aren't valid, alas.

Comment: ahhhh!! Very true! How can I simplify it though? @Semiclassical

Comment: The simplest way to proceed is probably to use a table of Laplace transforms. For instance, one can correctly complete the square in the denominator of $Y(s)$ as $s^2-s+1=(s-1/2)^2-1/4$, and expressions like that are typical in a transform table. That said, your reasoning after the (incorrect) simplification is also flawed: If $Y(s)=F(s)G(s)$, you _cannot_ conclude that $y(t)=f(t)g(t)$. (Which is what you've done in the second-to-last line.)

Comment: Oh! I understand! Okay thank you!

Answer (score 2):

$y'' - y'  + y = \delta (t-2)\\
s^2 Y - sy(0) - y'(0) - sY + y(0) + Y = e^{-2s}\\
(s^2 - s +1)  Y = e^{-2s}+ s - 1\\
Y = \frac {e^{-2s} - s+ 1}{(s^2 - s +1)}\\ 
(s^2 - s +1) = (s-\frac 12)^2 + \frac 34\\
Y = \frac {e^{-2s} - \frac 12}{(s-\frac12)^2 +\frac 34} + \frac {s-\frac 12}{(s-\frac12)^2 +\frac 34}\\ 
\mathcal L^{-1} \{\frac {s-b}{(s-b)^2 + a^2}\} = e^{bt} \cos at\\
\mathcal L^{-1} \{\frac {a}{(s-b)^2 + a^2}\} = e^{bt} \sin at\\
y = u(t-2) \frac 2{\sqrt 3} e^{\frac 12 t}\sin \frac {\sqrt {3}}{2} t - \frac 1{\sqrt 3} e^{\frac 12 t}\sin \frac {\sqrt {3}}{2} t + e^{\frac 12 t}\cos \frac {\sqrt {3}}{2} t$

Comment: God bless your soul!!